# Game of Thrones Catan: Can Othell move a road segment from an “interrupted” road chain?

Tags: catan

PlayerA has the longest road, via a long road-chain, like this:

`A - - - - - A`

PlayerB interrupts that road-chain with a settlement, like so:

`A - - B - - - A`

PlayerA has now lost Longest Road, because they no longer have an “unbroken road of at least 5 segments”.

Now the question we have is: **can PlayerA use Othell Yarwick to move the segments of this now-broken road?**

The text of Othell’s card is:

> “Remove 1 of your roads from the board and rebuild it for free at a
>   different legal location. The road you remove must only be connected
>   on 1 of its 2 ends to your own pieces. Ignore opponents’ pieces when
>   checking connections.”

...so that means that PlayerA can’t use Othell, right?

(I think I’ve just answered my own question by typing this up, but I wanted to post this question in case others also had it!)

Comment: You can answer your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

**No, Othell cannot move PlayerA's road segments.**

*Even though PlayerA lost their longest-road*, they cannot move these road segments - because, as Othell's card says, "The road you remove must only be connected on 1 of its 2 ends to your own pieces. Ignore opponents' pieces when checking connections."

Answer (score 1):

Correct. When ignoring opponents' pieces, that road piece is
connected on both of its sides to its owner's other pieces.